# Ominifaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler and FacesExceptionFilter redirection mistake from exception thrown by ManagedBean

Tags: jsf-2, omnifaces

In Tomcat7.0.40 JSF2.1 OF1.4.1 PF3.5
I have configured FacesExceptionFilter and FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory as in docs
 - http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler
 - http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/FacesExceptionFilter

I have also add in web.xml

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException</exception-type>
        <location>/errors/bug.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

After Login I go to a main page thru this navigation rule

```
 <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/stdPortal/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>mainPortal</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/stdPortal/stdPages/mainPortal.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

In mainPortal.xhtml i have a chart

```
                            <p:poll interval="60" update="graficoPresidio03Top" />

                            <p:barChart id="graficoPresidio03Top" value="#{mainPortalBean.graficoPresidio03Top}" legendPosition="ne"  
                                        style="width:1050px;height:300px" stacked="true" animate="true" xaxisAngle="45" seriesColors="ADFF2F, FFFF00, FFA500, FF4500"/>

                        </p:panel>
```

The chart is updated each time

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MainPortalBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5783190881181226264L;
    @ManagedProperty( value = "#{user}" )
    private UserBean userBean;


    public void setUserBean( UserBean userBean ) {
        this.userBean = userBean;
    }
    ....

    public CartesianChartModel getGraficoPresidio03Top() {
        createGraficoPresidio03Top();
        return graficoPresidio03Top;
    }
```

I have changed a for to create the Index out of bound exception

```
private void createGraficoPresidio03() {
    //here code with for modified
}
```

I get the current response in Tomcat LOG

```
lug 01, 2013 12:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception [An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean mainPortalBean] with root cause
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at com.telenia.tsam.beans.MainPortalBean.createGraficoPresidio03(MainPortalBean.java:815)
    at com.telenia.tsam.beans.MainPortalBean.init(MainPortalBean.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:96)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:64)
    at org.primefaces.component.spinner.SpinnerRenderer.encodeInput(SpinnerRenderer.java:122)
    at org.primefaces.component.spinner.SpinnerRenderer.encodeMarkup(SpinnerRenderer.java:103)
    at org.primefaces.component.spinner.SpinnerRenderer.encodeEnd(SpinnerRenderer.java:66)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabContent(TabViewRenderer.java:279)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:237)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:127)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.telenia.tsam.Filters.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

---

The problem is I'm not redirected to full error page but to a partially page miss a lot of its content.
In my app any other exception is correctly managed

eg:

```
lug 01, 2013 1:28:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception [/stdPortal/stdPages/config/centrale/List.xhtml @147,51 value="#{MM}": /stdPortal/stdPages/config/centrale/List.xhtml @146,103 value="#{cfgCentraleController.resolveMarca(centrale.idMarca)}": Property 'resolveMarca' not found on type com.telenia.tsam.beans.config.centrali.cfgCentraleController] with root cause
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /stdPortal/stdPages/config/centrale/List.xhtml @147,51 value="#{MM}": /stdPortal/stdPages/config/centrale/List.xhtml @146,103 value="#{cfgCentraleController.resolveMarca(centrale.idMarca)}": Property 'resolveMarca' not found on type com.telenia.tsam.beans.config.centrali.cfgCentraleController
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.Exporter.exportValue(Exporter.java:131)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.CSVExporter.addColumnValue(CSVExporter.java:219)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.CSVExporter.exportCells(CSVExporter.java:180)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.CSVExporter.exportRow(CSVExporter.java:158)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.CSVExporter.exportAll(CSVExporter.java:134)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.CSVExporter.export(CSVExporter.java:50)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:99)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1092)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.telenia.tsam.Filters.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

How to investigate in the corret direction? After reading this [FullAjaxExceptionHandler with datatable and lazydatamodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836325/fullajaxexceptionhandler-with-datatable-and-lazydatamodel)
I have no logs but Page are correctly managed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop doing business logic in getter methods. Getter methods are invoked during generating HTML output. However, if a part of that output has already been sent to the client due to response buffer being flushed, then there's means of a no point of return. You cannot take the alread-sent bytes back and present a completely different page (in this case, the error page). The client ends up with a halfbaked page because generating the HTML output has been completely aborted.

You should be doing business logic in action/listener methods, far before the HTML output is generated.

Change the abused getter method

```
public CartesianChartModel getGraficoPresidio03Top() {
    createGraficoPresidio03Top();
    return graficoPresidio03Top;
}
```

to be a [fullworthy getter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062)

```
public CartesianChartModel getGraficoPresidio03Top() {
    return graficoPresidio03Top;
}
```

and invoke that action method as poll listener instead

```
<p:poll ... listener="#{mainPortalBean.createGraficoPresidio03Top}" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, having an error page for a specific `RuntimeException` is a smell (it's a bug!). `RuntimeException`s should be fixed by changing the code logic in such way that it's never been thrown. E.g. by an `if` block which prechecks the demanding condition.

Comment: Thanks and as the usual a lot to learn, this should became a wiki.

Comment: OMG This is the source! WOW